# Rearrange row order of a matrix in r

Tags: r, row

I have the following data :

```
as.integer(datIn$Measurement.location)
myfunctionSD <- function(mydata) { return(sd(mydata,na.rm=TRUE))}
Alltubes <- tapply(datIn$Material.loss.interval,list(as.factor(datIn$Measurement.location),as.factor(datIn$Tube.number)),myfunctionSD)
```

From this I get the following output table:

```
           1         2         3         4         5         6
1  0.8710740 0.7269928 0.8151022 0.6397234 0.8670634 0.7042107
10        NA 0.8075675        NA        NA        NA        NA
11 0.6977951        NA 1.0984465 1.1148588 1.2156506 0.9620030
12        NA 0.5986758        NA        NA        NA        NA
13 0.8386249        NA 0.8398164 0.8833184 1.2469221 1.0070322
14        NA 0.5109903        NA        NA        NA        NA
15        NA        NA        NA 0.9391486 1.3571094 0.8375686
16        NA 0.5761583        NA        NA        NA        NA
17        NA        NA        NA        NA 1.0100850 0.7171070
19        NA        NA        NA        NA 0.5913518        NA
3  0.5580579 0.6106961 0.8971073 0.7046614 0.8456784 0.8001571
4         NA 0.7228325        NA        NA        NA        NA
5  0.9318795        NA 0.8961706 0.7753733 0.5915633 1.0471933
6         NA 0.5968613        NA        NA        NA        NA
7  0.7674944        NA 0.7196781 0.8543926 0.7778685 0.8697442
8         NA 0.6283008        NA        NA        NA        NA
9  1.3687895        NA 0.8815196 1.1723445 1.1589998 0.8194962
```

How do I rearrange the row numbers in the correct numeric order, so from 1 to 19 so I can plot it correctly?

Hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this...

```
> Alltubes[sort(as.numeric(rownames(Alltubes))), ]
```

Answer (score 1):

*df2 is your data frame*

```
 df2[order(as.numeric(rownames(df2))),]
          X1        X2        X3        X4        X5        X6
1  0.8710740 0.7269928 0.8151022 0.6397234 0.8670634 0.7042107
3  0.5580579 0.6106961 0.8971073 0.7046614 0.8456784 0.8001571
4         NA 0.7228325        NA        NA        NA        NA
5  0.9318795        NA 0.8961706 0.7753733 0.5915633 1.0471933
6         NA 0.5968613        NA        NA        NA        NA
7  0.7674944        NA 0.7196781 0.8543926 0.7778685 0.8697442
8         NA 0.6283008        NA        NA        NA        NA
9  1.3687895        NA 0.8815196 1.1723445 1.1589998 0.8194962
10        NA 0.8075675        NA        NA        NA        NA
11 0.6977951        NA 1.0984465 1.1148588 1.2156506 0.9620030
12        NA 0.5986758        NA        NA        NA        NA
13 0.8386249        NA 0.8398164 0.8833184 1.2469221 1.0070322
14        NA 0.5109903        NA        NA        NA        NA
15        NA        NA        NA 0.9391486 1.3571094 0.8375686
16        NA 0.5761583        NA        NA        NA        NA
17        NA        NA        NA        NA 1.0100850 0.7171070
19        NA        NA        NA        NA 0.5913518        NA
```

Comment: If this resolved your issue, @r.j.mendel, please consider *accepting* it by clicking on the check mark below the vote total to the left. You may also want to *upvote* these answers by clicking on the upwards triangle to their left.